# Installation of Jetstream in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

When I install the Jetstream in Laravel 8 by run this command in terminal:

> composer require laravel/jetstream

This error occured:

```
PS C:\Users\dell\Desktop\project> composer require laravel/jetstream
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/jetstream
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php ^7.3 but your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - fzaninotto/faker is locked to version v1.9.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.9.2 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/jetstream:*" to figure
out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/jetstream:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: Your PHP version is incorrect, it requires version 7

Comment: I have alredy install the last version of xampp the php version is 8.2.x

Answer (score 0):

open cmd in project path and run `php -v`.

if not seeing php version 8.2.4 you should add php path to windows env.

for more information see this link => **[Add XAMPP PHP to Environment Variables in Windows 10](https://dinocajic.medium.com/add-xampp-php-to-environment-variables-in-windows-10-af20a765b0ce)**